# Beamer not compiling presentation properly

Tags: beamer, preamble

I am making a beamer presentation, and it doesn't seem to want to be my friend.

> **The main problems:**
>
> **(1)**  When it compiles (pdflatex) the output is a series of slides, and after each \pause it makes a new slide with a higher number. That is to say:  clicking **does** uncover a new bit of information properly, but it changes the slide number which is annoying to say the least.
>
> **(2)**  The footer isn't working at all. I got a template which should do the usual thing for beamer slides and display the slide title, author, and which slide out of how many at the bottom, but it's just not doing this. The only thing that gets compiled at the bottom is a single digit representing which slide I am on.

**My guess:** I think there's something screwy in my preamble, but I just don't know enough of what's going on with all the moving parts to properly pin down the exact problem. I've included it below in case that's of any use.

```
 \documentclass[mathserif,18pt,xcolor=table]{beamer}
 
 \usepackage {bbm}
\usepackage {textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
 \usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}%
 \usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fullpage}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage{enumerate}
 \usepackage{stmaryrd,mathrsfs}
\usepackage{prettyref,hyperref}
 \usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,3d}
 
 [custom math-mode commands, omitted for brevity]
 
 \newcommand{\drawbox}[1]{\begin{array}{|l|}\hline #1 \\
 \hline\end{array}}
 
 
 \newtheoremstyle{thmstyle}{1em}{1.5em}{}{.7em}{\bf}{:}{0.5em}{}
 \theoremstyle{thmstyle} \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
 %\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} \newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
 \newtheorem{project}{Project} \newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
 \newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary} \newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
 \newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark} \newtheorem{ex}[thm]{Example}
 \newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
 \newtheorem{ithm}{Theorem}[section] \newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
 \newtheorem{question}{Question}
 
 \newrefformat{lem}{Lemma~\ref{#1}}
 \newrefformat{prop}{Proposition~\ref{#1}}
 \newrefformat{conj}{Conjecture~\ref{#1}}
 \newrefformat{def}{Definition~\ref{#1}}
 \newrefformat{sec}{Section~\ref{#1}}
 \newrefformat{thm}{Theorem~\ref{#1}} 
 \newrefformat{rem}{Remark~\ref{#1}}
 \newrefformat{cor}{Corollary~\ref{#1}}
 \newrefformat{fig}{Figure~\ref{#1}}
 
 \definecolor{utorange}{RGB}{203,96,21}
 \definecolor{utblack}{RGB}{99,102,106}
 \definecolor{utbrown}{RGB}{110,98,89}
 \definecolor{utsecbrown}{RGB}{217,200,158}
 \definecolor{utsecgreen}{RGB}{208,222,187}
 \definecolor{utsecblue}{RGB}{127,169,174}
 \definecolor{utgray}{HTML}{B2BEB5}
 
 \mode<presentation> {   % \usetheme{Pittsburgh}    % 
 \usetheme{Boadilla}     \usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
 
   \setbeamercovered{invisible}   \setbeamertemplate{navigation
 symbols}{}
 
   % Color Theme 
     \setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=white,fg=utblack}   \setbeamercolor{structure}{bf=utgray,fg=utorange}
 
   \setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red!85!black}
 
   \setbeamercolor{item projected}{use=item,fg=black,bg=item.fg!35}
 
   \setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,
 bg=utorange}   \setbeamercolor*{palette
 secondary}{use=structure,bg=utsecbrown}   \setbeamercolor*{palette
 tertiary}{use=structure,bg=utsecgreen}   \setbeamercolor*{palette
 quaternary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=utsecblue}
 
   % \setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{use=structure,fg=utorange,
 bg=utsecbrown}   \setbeamercolor*{framesubtitle}{fg=utbrown}
 
   \setbeamercolor*{block
 title}{parent=structure,fg=black,bg=utsecgreen}  
 \setbeamercolor*{block body}{fg=black,bg=utblack!10}  
 \setbeamercolor*{block title alerted}{parent=alerted text,bg=black!15}
 \setbeamercolor*{block title example}{parent=example text,bg=black!15}
 
   \setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\small} }
 
 \hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
 
 \usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=16,height=9.75,scale=0.5,debug]{beamerposter}
 %
 \usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=16,height=9,scale=0.5,debug]{beamerposter}
 
 
 \makeatletter \setbeamertemplate{footline} {   \leavevmode%
     \hbox{%
       \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author
 in head/foot}%
         \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor%~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
       \end{beamercolorbox}%
         \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title
 in head/foot}%
         \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
         \end{beamercolorbox}%
         \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date
 in head/foot}%
         \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}
         \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex} 
       \end{beamercolorbox}}%
         \vskip0pt% } \makeatother
 
 \usepackage{kerkis} \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
 \usepackage[protrusion=true,expansion=true]{microtype}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 
 
 \renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
 
 
 \pgfdeclareimage[height=1.0cm]{utbig}{logos/UTWordmark}
 \pgfdeclareimage[height=0.6cm]{ut}{logos/UTWordmark}
 \pgfdeclareimage[height=1.5cm]{sclogo}{logos/SC12} %
 \pgfdeclareimage[height=1.0cm]{scsmall}{logos/SC12}
 
 \title{title} %
 \subtitle{If you have one} \author[author]{ \underline{author}  }
 
 \institute{institute \\ \mbox{}  \\  \pgfuseimage{utbig}
 } \date[date]{\pgfuseimage{sclogo} \\ \today}
```

Comment: Oh no... You can simply select your code and hit `Ctrl+K` to mark it as a code. I don't know how to remove all those `>`s automatically here.... nevermind :)

Comment: It seems you fixed it. Thanks so much @percusse!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is some serious TeX slaying and package orgy happening which is normal if you don't have  a lot of TeX experience. I was like this too. Many of these stuff is for articles. So avoid loading these packages. For example, the reference stuff  Lemma, Conjecture bla bla you don't need at all. Because these are slides if you really have to use [`cleveref`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/cleveref) package but please don't.

So randomly removing stuff until it compiles gives me this.

```
 \documentclass[18pt,xcolor=table]{beamer}
 %\usepackage {bbm}
%\usepackage {textpos}
\usepackage{tikz}
 %\usepackage{amscd}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\usepackage{graphicx}%
 %\usepackage{fancyhdr}
%\usepackage{fullpage}
 \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
%\usepackage{enumerate}
 %\usepackage{stmaryrd,mathrsfs}
%\usepackage{prettyref,hyperref}
 \usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,3d}
 %
 %[custom math-mode commands, omitted for brevity]
 %
 %\newcommand{\drawbox}[1]{\begin{array}{|l|}\hline #1 \\
 %\hline\end{array}}
 %
 %
 %\newtheoremstyle{thmstyle}{1em}{1.5em}{}{.7em}{\bf}{:}{0.5em}{}
 %\theoremstyle{thmstyle} \newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
 %%\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} \newtheorem{conjecture}{Conjecture}
 %\newtheorem{project}{Project} \newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
 %\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary} \newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
 %\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark} \newtheorem{ex}[thm]{Example}
 %\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
 %\newtheorem{ithm}{Theorem}[section] \newtheorem{conj}[thm]{Conjecture}
 %\newtheorem{question}{Question}


 \definecolor{utorange}{RGB}{203,96,21}
 \definecolor{utblack}{RGB}{99,102,106}
 \definecolor{utbrown}{RGB}{110,98,89}
 \definecolor{utsecbrown}{RGB}{217,200,158}
 \definecolor{utsecgreen}{RGB}{208,222,187}
 \definecolor{utsecblue}{RGB}{127,169,174}
 \definecolor{utgray}{HTML}{B2BEB5}

 \mode<presentation> {   % \usetheme{Pittsburgh}    % 
\usetheme{Boadilla}     
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}
\setbeamercovered{invisible}   
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

   % Color Theme 
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{bg=white,fg=utblack}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{bg=utgray,fg=utorange}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red!85!black}
\setbeamercolor{item projected}{use=item,fg=black,bg=item.fg!35}
\setbeamercolor*{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=white,bg=utorange}
\setbeamercolor*{palette secondary}{use=structure,bg=utsecbrown}
\setbeamercolor*{palette tertiary}{use=structure,bg=utsecgreen}
\setbeamercolor*{palette quaternary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg,bg=utsecblue}

\setbeamercolor*{frametitle}{use=structure,fg=utorange,bg=utsecbrown}
\setbeamercolor*{framesubtitle}{fg=utbrown}
\setbeamercolor*{block title}{parent=structure,fg=black,bg=utsecgreen}
\setbeamercolor*{block body}{fg=black,bg=utblack!10}  
\setbeamercolor*{block title alerted}{parent=alerted text,bg=black!15}
\setbeamercolor*{block title example}{parent=example text,bg=black!15}
\setbeamerfont{framesubtitle}{size=\small} 
}

\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=FullScreen}
%\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=16,height=9.75,scale=0.5,debug]{beamerposter}
\usepackage[orientation=landscape,size=custom,width=16,height=9,scale=0.5,debug]{beamerposter}


 \makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{\leavevmode%
     \hbox{%
       \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{author in head/foot}%
         \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}\insertshortauthor%~~\beamer@ifempty{\insertshortinstitute}{}{(\insertshortinstitute)}
       \end{beamercolorbox}%
         \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
         \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle%
         \end{beamercolorbox}%
         \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.333333\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{date in head/foot}%
         \usebeamerfont{date in head/foot}\insertshortdate{}\hspace*{2em}%
         \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber\hspace*{2ex}% 
       \end{beamercolorbox}}%
         \vskip0pt% 
        }
\makeatother


 \pgfdeclareimage[height=1.0cm]{utbig}{logos/UTWordmark}
 \pgfdeclareimage[height=0.6cm]{ut}{logos/UTWordmark}
 \pgfdeclareimage[height=1.5cm]{sclogo}{logos/SC12} %
 \pgfdeclareimage[height=1.0cm]{scsmall}{logos/SC12}

 \title{title} %
 \subtitle{If you have one} 
 \author[author]{\underline{author}}

 \institute{institute \\ \mbox{}  \\  \pgfuseimage{utbig}}
 \date[date]{\pgfuseimage{sclogo} \\ \today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It looks like this fixes the problem, thanks so much!